# I need the height of the hidden in a scroll view Swift

Tags: swift, size, scrollview, height, hidden

Example image:

[image]

I need de height in color blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let height = scrollView.contentOffset.y
print(height)
```

insert it inside `scrollViewDidScroll`